# Phantomjs installation for Windows

Tags: phantomjs

I downloaded the "phantomjs-1.7.0-windows.zip " for Windows from [here](http://phantomjs.org/download.html).

I even set up the path of the extracted folder in the environment variables. But I am getting the "parse error" when I try to enter any command like `phantomjs --version` in the `phantomjs.exe` command prompt. (My Windows is 64 bit.)

Why is it throwing the error?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Type `phantomjs --version` in the Windows *command-prompt*.

If you launch PhantomJS by executing `phantomjs.exe`, you are now inside PhantomJS interactive mode (REPL). In this prompt, you should type JavaScript code.