# How Do I Configure Phantom.js?

Tags: javascript, html, localhost, phantomjs

Please help me to configure phantom.js on my Windows 8 PC.

I downloaded it from http://phantomjs.org/download.html

It gives me a zip file which has 1 .exe file that's it. When I open it, I get a console like screen. What do I do?

PS: I want to setup screen capturing javascript with phantom.js in localhost.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Phantomjs installation for Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12913172/phantomjs-installation-for-windows)

Comment: I already checked it. But I've no idea what I have to do. :( Please help, don't point out.

Comment: What about the [documentation](http://phantomjs.org/quick-start.html)?

Answer (score 0):

PhantomJS is a headless WebKit scriptable with a JavaScript API. It's a command line tool.

Assuming PhantomJS executable is placed somewhere in the current path, it can be invoked as follows:

```
> phantomjs [options] somescript.js [arg1 [arg2 [...]]]
```

It's not so difficult to create a script (read the [doc](http://phantomjs.org/documentation/)) and you can also find many good examples on internet.

There is a good example for screen capture : [rasterize](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/rasterize.js)

```
> phantomjs rasterize.js http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23016473/how-do-i-configure-phantom-js SO.png
```